# AndroidAsync Socket.io ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, socket.io, androidasync-koush

I am using socket.io 0.9.14 on the server and the 1.2.5 AndroidAsync library from koush. I get 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 exception when I use the  SocketIOClient.connect method.

Here is the attached stacktrace.
[image: Stacktrace for exception]